# How to access nested Lua tables from C

Tags: c, lua, lua-table

Let's say I want to set a value (e.g. a function) inside a nested table from the Lua C API.

```
-- lua.lua
glob = { 
  nest = { 
    -- set value in here
  }
}
```

How would I have to set the stack to access the inner table?

Is it just calling `gettable` multiple times and then a `settop`, like in the following code?

```
lua_pushstring(state, "glob");
lua_gettable(state, -1);
lua_pushstring(state, "nest");
lua_gettable(state, -1);

lua_pushcclosure(state, &func, 0);
lua_settop(state, "funkyfunc");

lua_pop(state, 2);
```

Comment: You need `lua_getglobal` and then `lua_gettable`

Comment: What do you intend to do with `lua_settop(state, "funkyfunc")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sets `glob.nest.name` to a C function:

```
lua_getglobal(state, "glob");
lua_getfield(state, -1, "nest");
lua_pushcclosure(state, &func, 0);
lua_setfield(state, -1, "name");
```

To add others field to `glob.nest`, just keep going:

```
...
lua_pushcclosure(state, &anotherfunc, 0);
lua_setfield(state, -1, "anothername");
```